# Is the Brill-Hartle average constant or does it vary from point to point?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

The Brill-Hartle average of a tensor field $A_{\mu\nu}$ is defined as

$
\left<A_{\mu\nu}(x)\right> = \int g_\mu^{\alpha'}(x,x') g_\nu^{\beta'}(x,x') A_{\alpha'\beta'}(x')f(x,x')\sqrt{-\bar g(x')}d^4x',
$

where $f(x,x')$ is some weighting function that decreases to zero when the difference of $x$ to $x'$ is greater than some scale $d$. Sometimes I find  $\left<A_{\mu\nu}(x)\right>$ being treated as a constant, although it clearly has a dependence on $x$ as the integral is over $x'$.

My questions are:

1) Why $\left<A_{\mu\nu}(x)\right>$ can be treated as a constant?

2) Shouldn't the behaviour of $\left<A_{\mu\nu}(x)\right>$ depend on the particular weighting function chosen?

My guess to both questions is that all this only show up in higher orders of the small parameters $h$ (weak field amplitude) and $\lambda/L$ (ratio of the wavelength of the curvature radius), but I can't see how.

Answer (score 0):

The Brill-Hartle average is actually an approximation of the EFE, (Einstein Field Equations) with a specific weighting function that is predicated on some general abstract constant, although it is dependent on non-quantum parameters. The tensor used by Brill-Hartle only has some determining constant that implies that when this specific function equates to this, then this function does that. This is not quantum mechanics, nor does it make any sense to make reference to beyond this juncture.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The Brill-Hartle average is a theoretical approximation of the EFE, which employs a generalized geometrical mathematical non-enumarable constant in the form of a tensor with coefficients that does not per se deterine a definite disposition of its average. These particular set of functions are only analytical or holomorphic.